# How to set a non-inline OnClickListener in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to attach a `View.OnClickListener` to a `Button`.  I don't want the `OnClickListener` to be an inline anonymous function definition.  Rather, I want to define it outside the bounds of the `onCreateView()` function.

In Java, I would do this as follows:

```
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                       Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
    View my_btn = view.findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
    my_btn.setOnClickListener(handleButtonClick);
    return view;
}

View.OnClickListener handleButtonClick = new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Log.d("my_tag", "click!")
    }
}
```

Other answers seems to suggest the following will work, but it does not compile for me:

```
    override fun onCreateView(name: String?, context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?): View
    {
        var view = super.onCreateView(name, context, attrs)
        my_btn.setOnClickListener( handleButtonClick  )
        return view
    }

    private val handleButtonClick = View.OnClickListener 
    {  
        view->
        Log.d("my_tag", "click!")
    }
```

What is wrong with the above, and how can I define an `OnClickListener` as a named property on my `Activity` class?

Comment: What’s the error you’re seeing

Comment: The error is: Error:(28, 46) Function invocation 'OnClickListener(...)' expected

Comment: Your second example does not declare the my_btn variable, did you forget to include it?

Comment: In an Android Kotlin project, any view in the layout xml file that has an id will get a member variable of the same name created on the Kotlin class automagically, so no need to declare

Comment: Maybe unrelated: Fragment.onCreateView and Activity.onCreateView do something completely different. Don't use Activity.onCreateView, it's not for inflating standard view hierarchies. Setup your view hierarchy in onCreate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indenting correctly fix the issue.

```
private val handleButtonClick = View.OnClickListener {  view->
    Log.d("my_tag", "click!")
}
```

as mentioned by others, as the `view` param is the single one and is ignored, you can get rid of it.

if you want using an object:

```
val handleButtonClick = object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        Log.d("my_tag", "click!")
    }
}
```

**Edit** : As mentioned by [@Mango](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48245355/how-to-set-a-non-inline-onclicklistener-in-kotlin#comment83479570_48246232), this is a limitation stated in the [grammar definition](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html).

Comment: omfg, this is it.  Putting braces on next line results in compiler error.  Did some DuckDuckGo-ing and found:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15195 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6739
What a petty, passive aggressive thing to do...

Comment: @duggulous Well, this is actually intended and is a syntax error. The grammar is much more restrictive - if the brackets are on _the next line_, this is interpreted as 1. a no-op retrieving `View.OnClickListener` and 2. an unused lambda.

Comment: @Mango Obviously it was intended by _someone_, but from what I've come to understand from reading up on this, the only technical reason why this occurs is because semi-colons were made optional.  In effect the compiler inserts semi-colons on each line under the hood.  Purely a matter of style and the creators decided to force their style preferences on everyone else.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want lambda notations then this might work for you:

```
val onClickListener = object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        //ToDo: Implement whatever method you need
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     infix fun View.click(click:()->Unit){
            setOnClickListener { click() }
}
```